# Getting last item in count variable

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm using WordPress and created a variable $post_count to track the number of posts.

Right now I'm using if($post_count == 1) to add a class if it's the first post, which works fine, but I can't figure out how to get the last post.

Would that be possible using just a variable to count posts? Or is there a better way to do this than creating a count variable? Here's my code so far:

```
if($query->have_posts()): $post_count = 0; ?>
    <div class="image-grid">
        <?php while($query->have_posts()): $post_count++; $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($post_count == 1) { ?>first_item<?php 
        } elseif() { ?>last item<?php } ?>">post content here</div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do

```
$query->found_posts;
```

to get the total number of posts. So:

```
if($query->found_posts == $post_count)
```

should work.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Works perfectly thanks!

Comment: For the sake of completeness it should be noted that `WP_Query::$found_posts` contains the number of total posts found, so in case pagination is involved one should use `WP_Query::$post_count` instead in order to be able to set the class for last item per page. Also you can use `WP_Query::$current_post` instead of a custom counter. @CadenGrant

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($query->have_posts()): $post_count = 0; ?>
    <div class="image-grid">
        <?php while($query->have_posts()): 
            $post_count++; 
            $query->the_post(); 
            ?>
            <div class="item <?php if($post_count == 1) { echo 'first_item'; } if( $query->found_posts == $post_count ) { echo 'last item'; } ?>">
                <?php //post content here ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```